# jQuery .delegate() not working on load and changeData events

Tags: jquery

Can someone enlighten me on the jQuery delegate, what events are handled and what aren't. The follow code doesn't work

```
$("#browser").delegate( ".photo", {
    "load": function(e) {
        alert("photo loaded");
    }
});
```

but the following code work

```
$(".photo").load( function(e) {
    alert("photo loaded");
} );
```

I also try to delegate changeData event to a class which doesn't work as well

```
$("#browser").delegate( ".thumbnail", {
    "changeData": function(e, prop, value) {
        alert( prop + " = " + value );
    }
});
```

but the following code work

```
$(".thumbnail").bind( "changeData", function(e, prop, value) {
    alert( prop + " = " + value );
}
```

Comment: Both answers you've gotten so far are correct. You're using the wrong syntax, and you cannot use `live` and `delegate` with those events.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not:

```
$("#browser").delegate( ".photo", {
    "load": function(e) {
        alert("photo loaded");
    }
});
```

But:

```
$("#browser").delegate( ".photo", "load",
    function(e) {
        alert("photo loaded");
});
```

And you cannot use live and delegate with those events, because they don't bubble.

Comment: I'm passing an object with multiple event: function() pair into one delegate, and it works on 1.5.1 for me ;)

Comment: Well, it's not in the documents, that doesn't mean that it doesn't work. Anyways, those events can't be used with live or delegate. So you'll have to find another way to achieve this. Like update the event binding on change.

Answer (score 6):

These events do not bubble, so they cannot be used with `live` or `delegate`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought load is a native javascript event, which should bubble. Do you mean the changeData trigger by jquery api itself is not a custom event or doesn't bubble. Anyway I can use delegate on both event?

Comment: I do look into the jquery code of changeData, and modify the triggerHandler to trigger so it can bubble. But I suspect it sometimes crash google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of jQuery, where the `.on()` method is favored before the `.delegate()` or `.live()` methods, it won't work in this way, too

```
// wrong
jQuery(selector).on('load', 'img', myFunc)
```

because the load event does not bubble

make it like this

```
jQuery(selector).find('img').on('load', myFunc)
```

Comment: This is **not** delegation.

Comment: It's a delegation in disguise.

Comment: I don't think this would work because `find('img')` finds the appended images but not those that will be loaded. Right?